# Help install Ubuntu 20.04 in Dell

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have DELL Precision T7910 Workstation

Content:
•   Processor CPU: 2 x Intel DECA Core Xeon E5-2650 v3 2.30 GHs, 25 MB Cache (2×20 = 40 Logical Processors)
•   Memory RAM: 124GB (8x16GB)
•   Hard Disk: 2 x 1TB HDD SATA
•   Place Video: nVidia Quadro NVS 295 – 256MB GDDR/64bit

I have installed EVE-PRO including Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit. I used for ~2 years.

I would like to change configuration. I would like to Install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop LTS, VMware PRO: EVE-PRO and other virtual things in VMware.

For Install Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit I use MacBook Pro to create USB and DVD.
I put USB in Dell, I power on, click F12, chose USB, start Install Ubuntu.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-drive-management

Stick when get to:

- A. Install type is leave Erase disk and install Ubuntu and click Continue.
- B. Erase disco and Install Ubuntu - Select Dive: SCSI2 (0,0,0,0)- 1,0 TB SEAGATE ST1000NM0001 => /dev/sdb (ext4). Click: Install Now.
- C. Remain here! Click: Install Now.
- back to A.
- Goes to B.
- Goes to C.
- Back to A.
- etc. etc. etc.
- Stick here!!!

I tried:

- Use DVD. Same problem!
- Try to use Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop LTS. Same problem!
- Put USB in diferent port. Same problem!
- Update Bios version from A32 la A34. Same problem!
- PowerON and Click F2 => Settings. Change things in General and Security Boot. Same problem!

Does anybody know what is my problem? Help me!!!

Comment: Did you verify the usb iso? Can you try the usb in a different machine, or ‘try Ubuntu’ (ie a live session) to confirm the usb installation media is working properly?

Comment: Your link https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-drive-management : Tick "Something else" to do your own choice of install partition(s).